# How does this statement function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: SQL select Statement]

This is a basic select statement, it starts out 'select' then all the rows coming from one table. Why are there '' and what function does that serve?
I know about using column and table aliases, or naming a column with a different name 'AS something'. I have seen this several times and never knew what it was trying to perform.

```
SELECT '' AS prSkipCustomInfo
       , '' AS WBS1
       , '' AS WBS2
       , '' AS WBS3
       , '' AS SubLevel1
       , '' AS SubLevel2
       , '' AS SubLevel3
       , '' AS WBS1Name
       , '' AS ProjectManager
       , '' AS Principal
       , '' AS Supervisor
       , '' AS ClientID
       , '' AS ContactID
       , '' AS ChargeType
       , '' AS revType
       , '' AS currencyCodeProj
       , '' AS currencyCodeBill
       , '' AS currencyCodeFunct
       , '' AS currencyCodePres
       , 0 AS currencyCodeProjCount
       , 0 AS currencyCodeBillCount
       , 0 AS currencyCodeFunctCount
       , 0 AS currencyCodePresCount
       , '' AS Account
       , '' AS TransType
       , '' AS SubType
       , '' AS Transfer
       , '' AS rectype
       , '' AS rectypelabel
       , '' AS rectypesub
       , '' AS rectypesublabel
       , 0 AS Period
       , 0 AS PostSeq
       , TransDate
       , '' AS RefNo
       , '' AS Desc1
       , '' AS Desc2
       , 0.00 AS Amount
       , '' AS Invoice
       , 0 AS Line
       , '' AS VendOrg
       , '' AS XferWBS1
       , '' AS XferWBS2
       , '' AS XferWBS3
       , '' AS BillStatus
       , '' AS AcctName
       , '' AS AcctClass
       , '' AS AcctSubClass
       , '' AS Org
       , '' AS Vendor
       , '' AS VendName
       , '' AS VendUnit
       , '' AS Voucher
       , '' AS Documents
       , '' AS PKey
       , 0 AS UnitQuantity
       , 0.00 AS UnitBillRate
       , 0.00 AS UnitCostRate
FROM   dbo.LedgerAP
```

Comment: Images of code are, more than often, not helpful. Post the code as text please, not as an image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is common pattern when you need some columns from table and the rest is simply placeholder to match desired resultset.

You will get as many rows as in table `dbo.LEDGERAP`.

```
SELECT
  '' AS prSkipCustomInfo,
  -- ...
   TransDate,                   --here goes actual value from source table
  --...
FROM dbo.LedgerAP
```

Answer (score 2):

The `''` is returning an empty string.

The simplest example of this is

`select '' as EmptyString`